# Tempfolder and its lifetime

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I have a little question: in windows 8 we have "tempFolder". How can i set lifetime for files, that i want to store in this folder?

Dev-center says about this:
"temporary: Data that could be removed by the system any time the app isn't running"
It's mean that, when app suspended(or minimized) they/system can remove files in temp? If "yes", how to force remove after some time?

Working with html5/js...

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove a file while the application is running.  The temp file simply holds files that aren't required to stick around between runs.  If you don't want a file to be used after a certain point, then have your application store the files in it's local folder.  When the file reaches its expiration date, then delete the file on application startup.